# docker ps Invalid bind address format:

Tags: docker, docker-machine

When I execute the command I get:

```
$ docker ps
Invalid bind address format: "tcp://192.168.99.100:2376"

$docker-machine rm -f default
$ docker-machine create -d virtualbox default
$ (docker-machine env default)
```

And now I can't list my docker images and containers.
What I can do to fix it?

Comment: Are the quotes part of your $DOCKER_HOST value ? If yes, that  _may_ be a problem and you could try to export DOCKER_HOST without quotes and check if it works.

Comment: Last command should be `eval $(docker-machine env default)`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Are the quotes part of your $DOCKER_HOST value ? If yes, that may be a problem and you could try to export DOCKER_HOST without quotes and check if it works.
>   Posted by – Christian W Oct 2 '17 at 14:56

This was the problem in my case:

export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://192.xx.xx.xx:2376"

Supposed to be:

export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.xx.xx.xx:2376

Comment: I had a similar issue. In my case it was because of `“ ”` characters enclosing the URL. Note they are not the regular `" "` quotes. I got a URL with those fancy quotes from a blog post. Changing them to `" "` made it work.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution which worked for me:

DELETE the DOCKER_HOST environment variable and reboot.

Refer to: [Docker Issue - Invalid bind address format Windows](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/431)

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove all `DOCKER_...` entries from your `.profile` file and add 
`eval $(docker-machine env default)`
at the end.

If that still gives you an error, reinitialize the docker machine as you did in the question.

Answer (score 0):

On windows we use SET command. Do following:

1. Restart docker machine
2. Run command `docker-machine env`
3. Copy variable DOCKER_HOST
4. Run command `SET DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.xx.xx.xx:2376`

This solved problem for us.